# Android Studio ImageView shows a white image

Tags: xml, image, android-studio

I am adding an image to my `LinearLayout`. Something very basic.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_logo"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/img_logo" />
```

Right click on the project folders, `New > Image Asset > Asset type` select `image` and choose the path to a `my_logo.png` or `my_logo.jpg` file. But both in Design and on my phone I only see a white square

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think it's a bug, mybe you can try create icon with this https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: it's probably a bug, which is surprising since I was expecting this is a feature that is largely used in android studio. 
Or it is a setting problem that covers my images when I import them with a certain color (white or gray).
Anyways, I generated the image with the tool that you linked and manually substituted each icon in the respective folders of my project and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In res > themes > themes.xml used
`android:tintMode` instead `android:tint`